# How to fix Dojo with iOS 7.1 keyboard issues?

Tags: javascript, ios7, dojo

When keyboard popup closes, the part of the view that it had covered stays “blank".

https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/17505

None of these suggestions really worked.

Any hint?

(iOS 7.1, dojo 1.9.3, cordova 3.4.0-0.1.3)

Answer (score 0):

Check for the screen resize event, then call the dojo resize

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    dojox.mobile.resizeAll();
};
```